# scaffolding seems not to work properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, scaffolding

I created a new asp.net MVC3 application (internet application), and then I added a new model with 3 classes:

```
public class BizCard
{
    [Required]
    public string BizCardID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public List<string> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public BizType type { get; set; }

    public List<BizService> OfferedServices { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class BizType
{
    public int BizTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}

public class BizService 
{
    public int BizServiceID { get; set; }
    public List<BizType> AllowedBizTypes { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

After that, I created a new controller, using the template "Controller with read/write actions and views using entity framework", I set the Model class to be "BizCard" and the data context class to be a new class which is called "BizDB". I was expecting to get a new class named BizDB that inherits from DbContext and includes 3 instances of DbSet:

```
DbSet<BizCard>, DbSet<BizType>, DbSet<BizService>.
```

In spite of that, I get the class with only one:

```
DbSet<BizCard>.
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this using EF Code First approach.

`1. So, you have to create a context class which should inherit DbContext containing required models as DbSet`

`2. Build the solution. Otherwise it will not be displayed at controller creation`

Then you can create the controller using necessary model and its dbcontext.

Comment: I thought that the class which is derived from DbContext is supposed to be automatically generated (Actually it's automatically generated, but not as I assume it has to be)